# How to handle auto rotation in an iOS app where one view should not be auto rotated and one view should?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Say, if it is a simple drawing program on the iPad, when the user draws a line from (0,0) to (730, 1000) in Portrait mode, the line is shown in its entirety.  But what if the user rotates the iPad 90 degree, if we allow auto-rotate, then the line will be cut off at the bottom.

So the view that contains the canvas should not be auto rotated.

On the other hand, if there is an undo button on the screen, or a slide out panel, then this part actually should be auto rotated according to the iPad's rotated state.

How is this best implemented?  Because usually we have auto rotate for everything, or no auto rotate at all, but this situation requires half and half.

Comment: Well, if you have the proper autosizing masks set, then the line will scale properly when you rotate it....

Comment: @lnafziger will the scaling affect the aspect ratio?  say, if the user draws a circle... won't want the circle to become an oval if rotated

Comment: Yes it will affect the aspect ratio.  Personally I would rather see the canvas with a visually perceptible drawing area and a different background area and still be able to rotate my iPad.  So in one view you will basically have a letterbox affect with bars at the top and bottom which can not be drawn on.  This will keep the same aspect ratio though.

Comment: @lnafziger so you mean only can draw in a 768 x 768 region? (or 748 x 748 if the status bar is allowed)

Comment: That's just one suggestion.  I personally hate it when I start an app and have to turn my iPad to use it.  I would rather have it functional any way it is turned, although perhaps "better" in another direction.  If I am switching between apps it can get very annoying though when some directions aren't supported!  Depending on your app, the rest of the space can be toolbars either on the side or top depending on which way it is facing.  Anyway, just my 2 cents.

Comment: I removed my answer since I misinterpreted what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with lnafziger that I have a hard time imagining that a user would want to have their drawing not rotate when they rotate the device. When drawing, the up-down and left-right aspects of the image are so integral to the creative drawing process that I would have thought that it would be very strange to see the controls on the view rotate, but not have the image rotate. Bottom line, I think you really want to preserve up-down and left-right of the image even as the user rotates the device. But I think you're absolutely right, that the user would find it disorienting if the aspect ratio of their image changed (i.e. if you squished the image) when they rotated the device.

Now, you've alluded to one solution that prevents the aspect ratio from being disturbed, i.e. keep the drawing image square, such as 768x768, and perhaps use the extra space for laying out some controls/tools. Even better, you might want to introduce the notion of the drawing consisting of a page that the user can pan/scroll around on. That way, you could make the image any size the user wants and when the user rotates the device, the image's "page" wouldn't change, just the little viewport onto that page represented by the iPad screen. And if you're convinced that the user wants to rotate an image, then give them a function to rotate the page, irrespective of the device orientation. You could easily map the coordinates of everything they wanted into the new space. That mapping should be pretty easy.

But, if you're determined to not rotate the image when they rotate the device (despite our insisting that this doesn't seem like a good idea), it seems like there two approaches (assuming you wouldn't contemplate the easiest solution, which is only permit one orientation in the app):

First you could remap all the coordinates of the objects the user draws and then redraw the objects once the rotation is done. Again, the remapping of all of the x,y coordinates when you rotate 90 degrees is pretty simple.

Second, you could put the drawing on it's own layer and then do a [CGAffineTransformRotate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) upon rotation of the device (e.g., if the user rotates the device 90 degrees, or PI/2 radians, clockwise, you'd rotate the layer PI/2 counterclockwise). It strikes me that this could get confusing as you draw new lines or other objects after the transform, as you might have to map the new coordinates to your transformed layer, but I'd suspect that you could get it to work. See the documentation for [CGAffineTransformRotate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) for more information. And if you google it, there are tons of examples out there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that maybe the drawn image probably shouldn't rotate. When people draw on pieces of paper they often rotate the paper to draw part of an image upside down or at an angle - this technique might be impossible if the image auto-rotated. Ideally user would be able to choose portrait or landscape image though. e.g. perhaps you should fix the image orientation when they start drawing.

What I would try first is implementing custom methods in your view controller that change the position and rotation of the elements:

```
-(void) updateLandscape;
```

and

```
-(void) updatePortrait;
```

and register for orientation change notifications:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];


- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if ( currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
        [self updateLandscape];
    } else {
          if ( currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
                [self updatePortrait];
          } else {
             if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                 [self updateLandscape];
             } else {
                 [self updatePortrait];
             }   
         }
     }
}
```